# Show that : $ x_n \overset {\sigma (X,X')}{\to} x $

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, weak-topology

Let $ X $ be a separeble reflexive Banach  space and $ (x_n)_n $ be a sequence of elements of $ X $ such that :

$(i)$. It admits a subsequence weakly converges to $ x \in X $

$(ii)$. Every limit point of $(x_n)_n $ must equal $x $.

Show that :
$$
x_n \overset {\sigma (X,X')}{\to} x
$$
An idea please

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the question may be wrong.

Consider the case that $X=\mathbb{R}$ (with real scalar field). Clearly,
the one dimensional Banach space $X$ is reflexive and separable.

Define 
$$
x_{n}=\begin{cases}
n, & \mbox{if }n\mbox{ is odd}\\
0, & \mbox{if }n\text{ is even}
\end{cases}.
$$
Clearly the subsequence $(x_{2n})$ converges to $x=0$ in norm, and
trivially $x_{2n}\rightarrow x$ weakly. Moreover, $(x_{n})$ has
only one limit point, namely $x=0$. That is, both condition s are
satisfied. However, it is false that $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly
because if $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ weakly, then for any $f\in X^{\ast}=\mathbb{R}$,
$fx_{n}=\langle f,x_{n}\rangle\rightarrow\langle f,x\rangle=fx$ (Here,
$fx$ means the product of $f$ and $x$), which obviously does not
hold.